# How to import mdl file into java through matlabcontrol?

Tags: java, matlab, simulink

I should use matlabcontrol to interact between matlab and java since I'm going to parse the data in java. Also I know that I should use get_param command to extract stored data in mdl files.

So, the question is here that,is it possible to import the extracted data into java work space through matlabcontrol. 
If yes, how?

Thank you in advance.:)